# Accessibility of a CSS Styled <a/> vs a Form-less Checkbox

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I'm upgrading the HTML for a site, and there is currently a list of items presented as filters or refinements that are marked up as check-boxes with labels, but not in a form. Then for "SEO reasons" they added an <a /> tag that isn't wrapped around it:

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="one" value="one" /> Refinement One
</label>
<a href="/url-for-adding-one"></a>
```

This is obviously not really adding full SEO value, and its kind of clunky HTML since the checkbox isn't necessary: the page works by listening for clicks on the label and firing an ajax load, all without a form. To be clear: there is no form, let alone a form submission, so the checkbox is there only as a visual cue. I want to replace it with background images on the anchor, and ditch the checkbox completely like the following:

```
<a href="/url-for-adding-one">Refinement One</a>
<a class="checked" href="/url-for-adding-two">Refinement Two</a>
```

The client is cool with this, but their main concern is with accessibility and how this change would be reflected to screen readers... my personal thought is that it must be better than checkboxes without a form, but I want a better answer that my gut-check.

Do you know of any accessibility implications of replacing checkboxes with links in this situation?

Comment: Checkboxes look differently on every platform. An image of a checkbox from a different platform may be confusing.

Comment: @Diodeus However, if it's done with an image such as "red X / green check" it would be fine - it all depends on the choice of image.

Comment: Form elements and links have *very* different meanings to UAs.  Clicking on a link says "go to this location", while a checkbox reflects a state change (true or false).  Whether or not there is a form involved is irrelevant (especially since HTML5 allows form elements to appear without a form).

Comment: @cimmanon Good point... Based on this, the question of "what is being accomplished" becomes important. In this case, which is more appropriate when the answer is "the current page is updated with new content like navigating to that page"?

Comment: "the checkbox is there only as a visual cue." - seems that with a background image instead, a sighted user has more information (checked/unchecked) than a screenreader user? A screenreader will just read out the link as "link" and the content, but not know anything about the checked-ness of it. That would be a problem if the checked-ness is more than purely cosmetic. (OTOH, both sighted users and screenreader users will get the same information where checkboxes are used.) Are you essentially trying to build a checkbox-equivalent out of an A here?

Comment: @BrendanMcK Good call out... and I think you might be right there, but I'm also specifically comparing this to implementations I'm seeing on Amazon that use an image of checkbox and an anchor; how would that address this problem better, or is that just as in-accessible?

Comment: @JonHartmann - are you talking about the "checkbox" links that amazon uses to refine product searches - eg if I search for laptop, I can then narrow down by screen size? Those have a bunch of accessibility issues; the ALT text for those doesn't even indicate the image meaning (eg "selected"), it's instead a dup of the link text (!) - there's no checked-ness conveyed to screenreader users. May be different use case anyhow; clicking those does cause an *entire page reload*, so they do behave more like navigation than typical interactive checkboxes that don't have navigation as a side effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer here is to use ARIA, in particular the [`aria-checked`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-checked) attribute. It's designed specifically for accessibility.

That said, I think your desire to get rid of the checkboxes is misguided. Anything that acts like a checkbox---i.e., it has a checked state and an unchecked state, which controls something on the page---should probably be a real checkbox. This gives you very nice behavior in terms of not only screenreaders, but also what keyboard and mouse users expect.

You can always wrap the `<a>` around the `<label>`.

Comment: Not that I think you're wrong, but how does this compare to Amazon which uses an image inside of an anchor instead of input[type="checked"] ?

Comment: Good question. Best answered by breaking out the screen reader on Amazon. Not sure how accessible they try to make their site.

Comment: Note that ARIA is necessary, but not sufficient; if you claim role=checkbox (which is prerequisite for aria-checked) , you also need to support expected keyboard behavior of a checkbox, which includes responding to space in addition to enter. Still best to stick with plain INPUT which does it all for you.

Answer (score 1):

If the page works by listening to clicks, then it in principle violates the accessibility requirement [“Make all functionality available from a keyboard”](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/#keyboard-operation). In practice, though, pressing Enter key in a focused element is generally treated as corresponding to clicking, i.e. a click event is triggered.

Checkboxes without a form are not a problem as such, never were. They can only work via client-side scripting, of course.

Using links might be related to history bookkeeping rather than SEO (because pages referred this way are seldom relevant in searches). If they are desired, then the choice is between making the control a link and duplicating it with a link. Duplication may cause confusion, especially in unusual browsing situations, so the link approach appears to be better. If the purpose of the link is to cause some action immediately, then it might be better to style it to look like a button. So a checkbox, even as a pure graphic, would appear to be unnecessary.

If it is necessary to show the user the options that have been taken (similarly to showing a checked checkbox), this could be done e.g. by showing a list of currently selected options (possibly along with buttons for unselecting).

Comment: Good answer Jukka, Yes, the user is shown a list of selected items (along with being shown the checkbox state), and the URL is updated (currently, the hash, but it is still a browse-able url). It sounds like I meet your qualifications for it being OK as an anchor instead of a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

The question is whether they end up looking like and behaving like checkboxes to sighted users. If these are items that visually appear to have a checked / unchecked state, and can have that state toggled by clicking, then they are behaving as checkboxes, so need to be exposed as such to screenreader users.

The problem with using plain anchors here is that the screenreader will just read them out as link elements, so a screenreader user will be expecting navigation to take place, not something that toggles state on a page. Also, no checked state information will be read out, so a screenreader user won't know if the item is checked or not.

The ideal situation here is to continue using real checkboxes, as in the original code. (Drop the empty `A` tag; it's a problem for keyboard users, as they can tab into it, but it has no screen presence - for sighted keyboard users - and has no content text, so screenreaders will just read out "link" leaving the user confused about what the focus is on.)

The advantages of using real `input type=checkbox` controls here is that they *just work*; sighted mouse users, sighted keyboard users and screenreader users all get good experiences. They are mouse and keyboard accessible; screenreaders will announce them as checkboxes, and convey the checked/unchecked state. (It doesn't matter that they are not in an actual HTML form.)

--

For what it's worth, if you did have some compelling reason to not use `input type=checkbox` and instead had to use an `A` that has been modified with click handlers and background images to behave as though it were a checkbox - and I don't think there's a good reason for going that route here! - then you could use the [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria.php) attributes to mark up the control with additional semantic hints so that screenreaders will announce it as a checkbox with correct state; this would involve adding [`role="checkbox"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#checkbox) and `aria-checked="true"`, for example. Also, since users expect checkboxes to respond to the spacebar as well as enter, you'd need to add keyboard handling for that also. And you'd need to test this with a screenreader to make sure it actually works. That's a lot of work to duplicate what `input` already does for you! This approach, however, does make sense when implementing custom controls that HTML does not already provide handy equivalents for, such as menus, sliders, treeviews and the like. Some of these will eventually - or are already - making their way into HTML anyhow.)

Comment: Not that I think you're wrong (you've made a very compelling case), but how does this compare to Amazon which uses an image inside of an anchor instead of input[type="checked"] ?

Comment: Also, although I think you're right about removing the anchors, I think that I'm going to be required to include them either way.

Comment: Would be good to understand why the anchors are required. If they just need to be in the source for book-keeping reasons, it might work to remove them using say `display:none` or removing them from the tree using javascript - which will prevent them from accidentally getting keyboard focus. Either way, try using the page using the keyboard yourself and verify that you can see where focus is at ever step of the way.